# Why Clear Button doens't work in my Javascript Calculator?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a Javascript Calculator. I have issues with my clear button, it just doesn't remove the entered symbols. What do I need to change in my code to make it work? Here's my code:

```js
function display(val) {
  document.getElementById("textval").value += val;
}

function compute() {
  try {
    var x = document.getElementById("textval").value;
    var y = eval(x);
    document.getElementById("textval").value = y;
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error.message);
  }
}

function clrText() {
  console.log(clrText);
  document.getElementById("textval").value = "";
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="title"> Calculator </div>
  <table border="4">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="c" onclick="clrText()/"></td>
      <td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="textval" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="display('+')" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="display('1')" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="display('2')" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="display('3')" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="display('-')" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="display('4')" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="display('5')" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="display('6')" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="*" onclick="display('*')" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="display('7')" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="8" onclick="display('8')" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="display('9')" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="display('/')" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="." onclick="display('.')" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="0" onclick="display('0')" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="=" onclick="compute()" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: share your `html` code too

Comment: Here it is up in the post.

Comment: there is an error in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <td><input type="button" value="c" onclick="clrText()"></td>
```

Remove the * / * near clrText() in your code and your it will work perfectly fine